# Adding an Event Handler for a List

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, event-handling

In Visual Basic.net, is it possible to add an event handler to a List of T such that whenever the list is changed, this event is called?

For example, if I have a Class called Schedule, and this Schedule has a List of ScheduleItem, how can I add an event that will be called whenever this List is changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are collections which raise events when the list changes (`BindingList(of T)` for one) but the events are only going to be available to the class/form where the list lives.  For a broader implementation your `Schedule` Class can raise events.

1. Make sure only `Schedule` makes changes to the list.  That is, your `List(Of T)` should be a private member.  Other objects should make changes thru it so that it is fully aware of all changes so that none are missed.
2. Decide what is a change event.  Add and delete an item are obvious, but depending on what is in `ScheduleItem` maybe `.StartTime` or similar properties are events as well. (That would actually require `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the item class)
3. For just Add and Delete, every time `Schedule` adds or deletes an item from the internal List, it would raise the event to notify the subscribers.
4. Who is going to consume (or get) these events?  Forms?  Other class structs?

A simple way to do this, once all changes are happening in the class which 'owns' the list is a custom event:

```
Public Class Schedule
    Private MyList as List (Of ScheduleItem)

    Public Event ScheduleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

     ...
   Public Sub AddItemToSchedule(....)
      ' I have no idea what is in a ScheduleItem....
      ...
      MyList.Add(si)
      ' the point is that if it gets added / not a dupe etc, then:
      ' tell any subscribers that the sched changed:
       RaiseEvent ScheduleChanged(Me, New EventArgs())
   End Sub

   Public Sub RemoveItem(...)
       ' do whatever to remove an item
       ' ... 
       MyList.Remove(si)
       ' tell subscribers the sched changed
       RaiseEvent ScheduleChanged(Me, New EventArgs())
   End Sub
End Class
```

An alternative to the private collection is for `Schedule` to inherit from something like `Collection(of T)`.  For the subscribers of the event:

```
Public Class SomeOtherClass

    ' These need a reference to the Schedule object
    Private WithEvents Sched As Schedule
    ...
    Public Sub New(scObj As Schedule)
        Sched = scObj
    End Sub
End Class
```

`SomeOtherClass` will now have a new entry in the Left VS Dropdown abs a related event:

```
Private Sub Sched_ScheduleChanged(sender As Object,
                  e as EventArgs) Handles Sched.ScheduleChanged
     ' add code here to respond to schedule changes

End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Dim foo = New SomeOtherClass(SchedObj)
```

Whatever is creating the `SomeOtherClass` object passes the `Schedule` object in the constructor.  If it is being created by `Schedule` it would be `Me`.

If `SomeOtherClass` has access to `Schedule` you can forego the constructor argument:

```
Public Sub New()
    Sched = mainSchedInstance
End Sub
```

**In all cases**, `Schedule` needs to exist or the code will be trying to hook to events on a `Nothing` object.

**Notes**

- It might seem odd to pass the `Sched` object (`Me`) in all the events
  (who else would send `ScheduleChanged` events?).  But the VS code analysis tools object to an event signature other than `Object sender, EventArgs e`.
- If you want to pass information in the event such as what *type* of change, create a class which inherits from `EventsArgs` and add whatever properties you want.  One of those could be the `ScheduleItem` added

There are other ways to implement this, for instance of it was `Foo.Schedule` and `SomeOtherClass` needs to know about the event.  In this case, Schedule still generates the event, `Foo` subscribes to it and then raises its own `ScheduleChanged` event, passing along the event args.  Other actors subscribe to the event on `Foo`.  This is referred to as 'bubbling up' an event.

---

You can also create a small class with one method and does nothing more than raise an event. In this case, it would be created by `Schedule` and be available to any actor via a non private member.  `SomeOtherClass` could get a reference to the `Schedule.ScheduleChangeNotifier` from Foo.  When the list changes, `Schedule` calls the method which fires the event and Foo isn't involved.

This pattern is usually called an EventBus, but it can be thought of as a Broadcast-Receiver setup: Schedule uses the class to broadcast a notice, others use it to receive them as an event.  It is useful when there is otherwise no need for the 2 actors to even know about each other.

An example would be `Foo.Bar` needing to know about something from `Fizz.Blorg`: `Bar` could receive those events without involving `Fizz` or `Foo` beyond getting the bus/notifier object to `Bar`.

It is less common than bubbling up events but sometimes very useful.  Usually though if it seems that is the answer, I try to re-examine the design to see if things could be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

`List(Of )` doesn't provide this out of the box.

You can either create your own implementation of `IList(Of )` and implement the events you want or you could using existing collections like `BindingList(Of )` or `ObservableCollection(Of )`.